# ¿Cómo retener valor usando cálculo de porcentaje PHP?

Tags: php

Necesito realizar operaciones de retener del valor ciertos porcentajes por ejemplo cuando se envía un pago por PayPal el que recibe, PayPal le hace una retención en porcentajes por decir una retención de `4.5%`. (cuatro punto cinco) de retención.

Yo necesito trabajar de dicha manera, poder usar retenciones de cualquier porcentajes ejemplo: `2% 3.5% 75%  60.5%` entre otros.

Aplicando el procediendo de está manera no obtengo resultados consiguientes:

```
 //Valor
  $a = 100;
   //Retener
   $b = 50;
    $resultado = $a % $b;

    echo $resultado;
```

Debería obtener del valor de `$a` el total de `50` ya que se está aplicando una retención del 50%.

Es muy distinto al siguiente procedimiento:

```
  //Valor
  $a = 100;
   //retener
  $b = 2;

  $resultado = $a / $b;
  echo $resultado;
```

Resultado es 50, se puede decir que obtuvo la retención del 50% pero si deseo trabajar en descuentos de porcentaje como ya lo especifique no podría con esta opción.

¿Cómo puedo realizar estás operaciones, no soy muy bueno en el tema matemático en PHP?

Comment: El problema no es que no seas bueno en matemático sino que no has revisado para qué es el operador `%` en la documentación de PHP. Si tomas este hábito y miras, por ejemplo [aquí](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), verás que ese operador no sirve para lo que buscas y no se entiende bien por qué comparas los dos códigos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para calcular el valor que deseas retener, deberías hacer una regla de 3, y operarala del modo que te muestro

1.Siempre usa signos de agrupación como: `[]`, `()` ya que de lo contrario puedes esperar un comprotamiento extraño en tu operación
2.Analiza la operación de este modo, por ejemplo la suma total son 500 dólares, de eso quieres retener el 25%; entonces el enunciado debe quedar mas o menos asi

```
500 -> 100
?   -> 25
```

> Multiplica 25 * 500 y el resultado dividelo entre 100

```
<?php

 //Valor
  $a = 500;
   //Retener
   $b = 25;
$resultado = ($a * $b)/100;

    echo $resultado;
```

***ACTUALIZACIÓN***

Ahora para saber al final cuanto vale $a, no hay mas que hacer una resta de $a-$resultado e imprimir

```
<?php

 //Valor
  $a = 500;
   //Retener
   $b = 25;
$resultado = ($a * $b)/100;

    echo $resultado;
    echo $a-$resultado;//dará 375
```

El operador % se llama módulo y esta presente no solo en PHP, te ayuda a obtener lo que sobra al hacer de una división; te pongo 2 ejemplos

```
echo 10 % 2; //dará 0 por que 10 entre 2 es 5 y no hay residuo

echo echo 10 % 3;// dará 1
```

> por que 10 entre 3 es un número periodico por que no termina, queda
>   así 3.3333333 entonces el sobrante es 1 por redondeo

Comment: Genial, se hace la retención, pero como se el valor que tiene $a al aplicarse la retención?

Comment: te actualizo mi respuesta @Hulk

Comment: Estupendo, no se veía tan complicado gracias :) ese operador `%` cuando y donde de usa existe una pregunta aquí que hable sobre el tema que no sea la documentación de PHP porque no está muy claro en su documentación.

Comment: @Hulk te agregué la explicación al final